# List files from Http Server using Java without having to parse the HTML page manually?

Tags: java

I want to get a list of files from a given URL.
When using the browser, the site looks like this:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.9/

Currently, I'm getting it as an HTML page, and parsing it for the files manually.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does the server handle ftp?

Comment: how do I find this out? I tried to replace https : // www.something with ftp : // ftp.something and it doesn't work. "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Did you try `ftp://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.9/`?  (Doesn't work for me though).  To answer your question: probably not, unless their server has some kind of API.